# Add hyperlink to picture using VBA Macro in PowerPoint

Tags: vba, hyperlink, powerpoint, powerpoint-2013

I am trying append a hyperlink to an image, on Click, to the Master Slide page of a PowerPoint using VBA/Macros. I have added the photo and am now  looking for a function that will add **'www.comment.com/connect'**

```
Private Sub commentConnect_Click()
    ...
End Sub
```

Should I use the  **`.Hyperlink.Address = "www.comment.com/connect"`** function?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a reference to the image (or any other shape) in the variable oSh:

```
With oSh
    .ActionSettings(ppMouseClick).Hyperlink.Address = "http://www.pptfaq.com"
End With
```